# Mongo: document read-with-lock and update

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Mongo newbie question!

Is there a way to do single document transaction in mongo? i.e. typically read with lock, modify data and update the document like in traditional SQL.

If not, what are the alternatives to enforce the same?

I was wondering if a 'lock' collection can be created where every client trying to update the collection e.g. 'users' create an entry for 'userid' it wants to lock. The 'lock' collection enforces uniq indexing on 'collection+id'.

The flow would be,
1. Client attempts to insert {"lockid":"users+userid"} in 'Locks' collection
2. If insert fails, wait and repeat step-1
3. Read record from 'users'
4. process user record
5. Write processed user record to 'Users'
6. Delete entry created in step-1

Any other thoughts?

Thanks for inputs!

Comment: How about optimistic locking (with an always increment version field on the document)? Then you can detect a concurrent update and retry/abort/merge.

Comment: thanks! I'm trying to implement my sever side logic in golang with mgo driver. Not sure if this would be possible, but would explore further.